# Given cube of size n^3, find no of smaller cubes on surface

Tags: algorithm, cube

Studying up for interviews and going through [these questions](http://www.techinterviews.com/amazon-interview-questions).

> 8.Given a cube of size n*n*n (i.e made up of n^3 smaller cubes), find the number of smaller cubes on the surface. Extend this to k-dimension.

I don't understand the question very well. For one side, we'll have n^2 number of cubes on the surface. And there are 6 sides on a cube, so is the answer just 6n^2? That seems too simple to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your solution counts cubes more than once. Remember that cubes on an edge will have faces on up to two other sides.

Comment: @mteckert good point, so for two sides we have the entire side. for the other four we don't count the edge cubes. so it's `2n^2 + 4(n-2)^2`. Does that look right?

Comment: Visualize a Rubik's Cube. Only one of the smaller cubes is unexposed to the surface. From this information, you can see your equation does not hold for 3x3x3. (Hint: do two entire faces account for *all* the edge cubes on the remaining faces?)

Comment: @mteckert of course you are right again. Let's go about it the other way, what is not on the surface? For 3x3x3, one is in the middle. For 4x4x4, 2^3 are in the middle. so is it `n^3 - (n-2)^3` in other words `all - middle`?

Comment: Yes! This is probably the solution James Black was hinting at.

Comment: @mteckert nice, thanks for the help. If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can post it yourself and accept it, since it was you who came up with it. (This is fine/encouraged on SO)

Comment: @jb - Congrats on figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a cube that is 4x4x4, so it would contain 64 cubes of size 4, how many of these cubes are on the surface?

I would do it for 3 and 4, then come up with an equation, and test with 5.

Basically, how many of the cubes don't touch the surface is another way to look at it.

Comment: please see my comment on the question. Does that look right?

Answer (score 1):

There are n^2 1*1*1 cube in one side, but there are (n-1)^2 2*2*2 cube in each side and ... 3*3*3, ...